# Send To Documents Copies Files Instead of Moving Them

Tags: windows-7, file-management, documents, send-to

When I right-click on a file, then select `Send To | Documents`, the file is copied into my Documents folder, not moved.  Is there any way to change this behavior in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post at [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-copy-to-move-to-on-windows-vista-right-click-menu/) offering a "Move to" and a "Copy to" option in the context menu.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could just push the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when selecting your SendTo option.

Comment: Still working in X ver2004! You smashed it! much easier for sorting a discombobulation of files n folders quickly. Just paste destination links in `shell:sendto` first.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  I think by default it copies the file.  One way that I over come wanting to "move" rather than "copy" files is to use the cut option or a program such as [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/).  You can actually "move" files very easily.  I just keep it open all the time so it's ready when I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bat file with this:

```
Set MoveTo="C:\"

for %%f in (%*) do @move %%f %MoveTo%
```

Put a shortcut of this bat file in your send to directory and now you can right click a file
and choose send to --> "your shortcut". The file will be moved to the `MoveTo` location.

Answer (score 0):

The answer with the .bat was almost perfect..but at first it didn't work.
First things first make sure that the destination folder has right permissions..so for start open command prompt and make a simple move

```
move directory destinationFolder
```

If its goes well proceed else right click destinationFolder and make sure that User have full permissions.
Then make a .bat file somewhere and copy paste the code below

```
Set MoveTo="destinationFolder"
for /D %%b in (%*) do @move /Y "%%~fb" %MoveTo%
```

Open the sendTo folder by going to RUN --> **shell:sendto** and paste the shortcut of the above .bat